# Formatting keywords, data in algorithm2e

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithm2e

I am just wondering if there is a way to reference the keyword data outside the algorithm in algorithm2e package. For example, given the example in algorithm2e, if I want to reference \KwData{this text} in my text outside the algorithm, how should I do it?

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetLine
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{
read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Would you show us a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) of how you intend to use it and also the expected output? You can use `\KwData` *outside* the `algorithm` environment.

Comment: @Werner, what MWE do you need, I am just asking how to reference the keyword outside of algorithm, I mean I haven't got a clue how to do it, I do not even know how to make a MWE.

Comment: What do you mean by "reference"? Typically a reference refers to a "cross-reference" where you use `\label`...`\ref`. But I'm not sure whether this is what you're after. So I was asking about what you exactly want in return (say, `this text`) for this "reference" (if that's what you're after). The **Data:** is formatted using `\KwSty`, but `this text` is formatting as regular text.

Comment: @Werner: the reference I meant is indeed \label....\ref, the keyword data in the algorithm are formatted with special fonts, ultimately, what I want is to use exactly the same fonts in text as they are used in algorithm to maintain consistency. Hope this clarifies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example you've given, `this text` is completely unformatted, and it's best to use it as-is in your text. However, components of an `algorithm` are styled using various macros:

- `\DataSty{<stuff>}`

  Used to set data (default is `\textsf`):

  [image]
- `\ArgSty{<stuff>}`

  Used to set arguments (to functions; default is `\textit`):

  [image]
- `\KwSty{<stuff>}`

  Used to prefix input parameters for an algorithm (default is `\textbf`):

  [image]
- `\FuncSty{<stuff>}`

  Formatting of a function name (default is `\texttt`):

  [image]
- `\CommentSty{<stuff>}`

  Formatting of comments (default is `\texttt`):

  [image]
- `\TitleSty{<stuff>}`

  Used to set the title of the algorithm via `\TitleOfAlgo` (default is regular text):

  [image]
- ...

I would use the appropriate style in the text as well, like in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\SetKwData{matrixinput}{some matrix}%
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \KwIn{\matrixinput}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

We use \matrixinput as input.
\end{document}
```

The input `\matrixinput` is defined *outside* the `algorithm` environment in order to make it usable outside of that scope (without your text).